# Is it possible to create desktop Java apps with RubyMotion?

Tags: ruby, windows, macos, desktop-application, rubymotion

I would like to create a desktop app that targets both OSX and Windows. Is it possible to do this using RubyMotion?

Answer (score 0):

With RubyMotion you can target Android, iOS and OSX but not Windows. As stated on its site:

> RubyMotion lets you quickly develop cross-platform native apps for
>   iOS, Android and OS X, all using your favorite editor and the awesome
>   Ruby language you know and love

If you want to make and Windows compatible app then I will suggest you looking at [Shoes](http://shoesrb.com/) and [FxRuby](http://www.fxruby.org/)